# Class not found for custom plugin block when trying to do dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I'm attempting to create a custom plugin block in Drupal. When attempting to actually access the services that I've registered I continue to get the following exception:

```
NOTICE: PHP message: Error: Class 'Drupal\MyNamespace\MyRegisteredService' not found in /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 259 #0 /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(173): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'foo....')
```

I have registered the services correctly, and have set up dependency injection correctly (I believe) it's just accessing the services that is not working.

My file structure currently looks like:

```
- web
  - modules
    - custom
      - foo
        - foo.services.yml
        - src
          - MyService.php
          - Plugin
            - Block
              - FooBlock.php
```

foo.services.yml looks like:

```
services:
  foo.my_service:
    class: Drupal\MyNamespace\MyRegisteredService
    autowire: true
```

FooBlock.php looks like (simply for dependency injection):

```
namespace Drupal\foo\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\MyNamespace\MyRegisteredService
use Drupal\Console\Bootstrap\Drupal;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Http\Client\Exception;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\Array_;
use stdClass;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


class FooBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  private $my_service;

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('foo.my_service'),
    );
  }

  function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    Drupal\MyNamespace\MyRegisteredService $my_registered_service,
  ) {
    $this->my_registered_service = $my_registered_service;
  }
```

MyService.php looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MyNamespace;

class MyService
{
  static function say_hello()
  {
    return 'hello world';
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if the way that I'm trying to set this up is incorrect or if I haven't set up dependency injection correctly. Some things that I have tried with no success is changing the namespace and removing `Drupal\` from it but this changed little.

I've also tried following several guides (such as [this](https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-define-your-own-services-drupal-8)) on how set up services, with little luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the actual name of your service or namespace path, but I can see a few inconsistencies in your placeholder references:

- Please change all references of `Drupal\MyNamespace\MyRegisteredService` to `Drupal\foo\MyRegisteredService` where `foo` is the name of your module. This should be lower cased.
- Secondly `Drupal\MyNamespace\MyRegisteredService` references a class name `MyRegisteredService` whereas the example class name you give is `MyService`. These should be equal, so either go with one or the other.

Comment: My issue was related to how the namespaces were defined, the class name was an error on myside renaming things.  Change `Foo` to `foo` resolved the issues.